# C# Webview2 control on a Microsoft Surface Pro

Tags: webview2, surface-pro

We have a Windows Forms application where we recently updated the old WebBrowser control to Webview2 - version 1.0.961.33. Everything works great except on Microsoft Surface Pro. The error we get is:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from H`RESULT: 0x8007000B`).

I found one article that said I should change the user agent string for Microsoft Edge but that doesn't seem to be working. The app ships with `Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll`, is there a 64 bit version of this DLL that should be used with the Surface Pro?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you shipping `WebView2Loader` also? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution

Comment: We are requiring users to manually install the runtime. If the runtime is not installed we see the error: "Couldn't find a compatible Webview2 Runtime installation to host WebViews."